# Is there a way to exclude 3 digit numbers ending in 11 using regular expressions?

Tags: regex, phone-number

I am trying to validate **phone number area codes** (North America) checking that the number does not start with a one or a zero.  Also, the number should not include reserved numbers such as these (i.e. excluding everything ending in 11).

- These would be valid area codes: 414, 608, 920, 319, 715
- These would NOT be valid:  023, 123, 411, 611, 811, 911

I have tried several things, but still no luck.  I am not very good at regex. Here is my latest try

```
\b([2-9](?!11)|[2-9][0-9]{2})\b
```

Comment: There's a lot of text explaining what is required.  You may get more answers if you post a list of number styles to match and then a list that should not match.  Even if it is not perfect you could see how they approached it and tweak the regex yourself or update the question to cover the new false positives discovered.

Comment: Thank you I made the examples much simpler.

Comment: Rough first attempt https://regex101.com/r/p6Q79H/1 which matches 414, 608, 920, 319, 715 and doesn’t match 023, 123, 411, 611, 811, 911

Comment: OP can you indicate which flavour (tool/library) of regex you're working with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt is very close, you do not need the "either" expression in your matching condition, just a negative lookahead, that will stop the match if it sees the string. Here is an example of some working regex:

```
([2-9](?!11)[0-9]{2})
```

You can try it out [here](https://regex101.com/r/YDUMFw/1)

Answer (score 1):

Solution without negative lookaheads:

```
([2-9][02-9][0-9]|[2-9][0-9][02-9])
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work as required including the 0 and 1 caveate.

```
        String pat = "[2-9]\\d{2}(?<!11)";
        String[] data = {"123","001","212", "321", "449","811", "121", "111", "911", "099"};
        for (String s : data ) {    
            System.out.println(s + " " + (s.matches(pat) ? "valid" : "invalid" ));
        }
```

Prints

```
123 invalid
001 invalid
212 valid
321 valid
449 valid
811 invalid
121 invalid
111 invalid
911 invalid
099 invalid
```